# Classes in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

Recently started learning ruby and I've created a class for family members that contains name, age, sex, marital status, and traits. I am trying to write a method that will determine if a family member is a parent and if whether or not its the mother or the father.

so the code for the method is as follows:

```
def is_father?(age, sex)
    if age > 30
      puts "is parent"
          if sex == "Male"
            then puts "is father"
          else puts "not father"
          end
    end
  end
```

And a family member might look like this:

```
fm1=Family.new("John", "Male", 54, "Married", "Annoying")
```

after being initialized like this:

```
class Family
  def initialize(name, sex, age, status, trait)
    @fam_name=name
    @fam_sex=sex
    @fam_age=age
    @fam_stat=status
    @fam_trait=trait
  end
end
```

If a person contains the previously mentioned characteristics, how do I just pass age + sex into this method? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Some sexual education might be called for here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store your data during initialization in attributes. later you can use them without using parameters of the method.

Example:

```
class Family
   def initialize(name, sex, age, status, trait)
    @fam_name=name
    @fam_sex=sex
    @fam_age=age
    @fam_stat=status
    @fam_trait=trait
  end
  def is_parent?; @fam_age > 30;end
  def is_father?
    is_parent? and @fam_sex == "Male"
  end
  def to_s
    result = @fam_name.dup
    if @fam_age > 30
      result <<  " is parent and is "
          if @fam_sex == "Male"
            result << "father"
          else 
            result << "not father"
          end
      end
    result
  end
end

fm1=Family.new("John", "Male", 54, "Married", "Annoying")
puts fm1.ilding is_parent?
puts fm1.is_father?
puts fm1
```

Remarks:

- I modified your `is_father?` - methods ending on `?` normally returns a boolean value.
- I moved your text building to method `to_s`. `to_s` is called if you print your object with `puts`.
- Better you avoid `puts` inside your methods. Most of the times, it is better to return an answer string and make the `puts` when you call the method.

---

Perhaps I misunderstand your request.

If `is_father?` is no method of Family and you need access to the attributes, then you must define a getter method:

```
class Family
  def initialize(name, sex, age, status, trait)
    @fam_name=name
    @fam_sex=sex
    @fam_age=age
    @fam_stat=status
    @fam_trait=trait
  end
  attr_reader :fam_sex
  attr_reader :fam_age
end

fm1=Family.new("John", "Male", 54, "Married", "Annoying")
puts fm1.fam_sex
puts fm1.fam_age


is_father?(fm1.fam_age, fm1.fam_sex)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll have it working soon enough!

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialized age/sex/etc you can use them in any method by `@age`/`@sex`/`@etc`

```
def is_father?(age = nil, sex = nil)
    if (age || @age) > 30
        puts "is parent"
    end
    if (sex || @sex) == "Male"
        puts "is father"
    else 
        puts "not father"
    end
end
```

In example above if you pass values to the method, they will be used instead ones set at initialization

Answer (score 0):

Using Struct can save a banch of code

```
class Family < Struct.new(:name, :sex, :age, :status, :trait)
  # define methods in usual manner
end

f = Family.new("John", 'male') #<struct Family name="John", sex="male", age=nil, status=nil, trait=nil>
```